# using android mobile as a server

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am developing a turn based two player android game. Is it possible to use one of the user's mobile as server rather than an external server to coordinate the game ?
I do not need much data storage. only 40 fields(text or numbers) to be stored and transmitted (for transmission , one value at a time) while the game is on. after game is over only user's current score is to be stored. 
I guess to do any such thing I need to get ip of the mobile. Is it possible ?

Comment: For that, mobile's ip should be static. But still its not correct approach

Comment: @SeshuVinay is mobile ip static ?

Answer (score 2):

You need more than just the IP since the IP is just an endpoint on the Internet and there is no guarantee that it is your device that answers if you talk to that IP. There is usually a local network behind that IP and you can't access devices in there with just the public IP.

The problematic part is establishing a direct connection which is (usually) not possible on the Internet unless you are in control over the Internet connectivity (router etc) and can setup port forwardings / firewall rules / whatever blocks direct connections. If you have no access - for example because you use 3G where the "router" is at your provider's datacenter - you will need at least a server to do things like [hole punching](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html).

Also a server used to find other's games (and IPs) would be a good idea.

You can however do all that if both devices are on the same WiFi and they can see each other directly.

Comment: what it takes for two mobile devices to talk directly using internet connection say 2g or 3g ?

Comment: [[Hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching)] and if that fails you have to transfer data via a 3rd party that allows direct connection

Answer (score 0):

I am from Skiller and I think we have exactly what you need.
@zapl is right, if you want your players to connect to your games using 3G or WIFI connection the best solution will be intermediate server that makes it possible to exchange data between the players. Setting up, hosting and scaling such a server may be very expensive and time consuming thing. We provide FREE SDK tools, using which you will be able to set up your turn based two player game in no time. We are handling all the server side maintenance so you could just implement the game logic and fire your game to the market asap.

Download the SDK from [www.skiller-games.com](http://www.skiller-games.com) and tell me what you think.
If you have any questions write us here or to developers@skiller-games.com

Comment: What is the real cost of your product (it is not very clear on your website and should definitely be in the FAQ)? Do you take 50% of all sales and ad revenue the developer makes?

Comment: @Sebastien, The SDK is FREE of charge, we are working on a revenue share model with the developers. We have renewed our EULA a few months ago and currently, when the developer includes one of Skiller's monetization features to generate more revenues from his game (virtual currency, virtual goods or advertising), we would share only those revenues, giving 70% to developers.

Comment: OK thanks, I guess I had read an old version of the EULA. So a developer who doesn't use your monetization features will share no revenue with Skiller, and Skiller won't show any unwanted ads ?

Comment: @Sebastien, when using Skiller advertisement services, the developers retrieve the advertisement and place it wherever they want in their game. Skiller SDK is not intrusive and does not place unwanted ads in your game screens. If you want to clarify any other subject in EULA  please contact our support department at developers@skiller-games.com and they will gladly answer any of your questions.

Comment: @MichaelLiberman right now you are using sql, which is not very scalable. r u planning to move to nosql in near future ?

Comment: @JohnWatson, our mission is to take care of the servers and databases scalability, maintenance and survivability to enable the developers to concentrate on their games and shorten the time to market. Our back-end technology, business logic and optimizations, serve this purpose exactly.